# Reverse the `pairwise` generator

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I've got a generator similar to the itertools' `pairwise` recipe, which yields `(s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3)...`. I want to create another generator from it that would yield the original sequence `s0, s1, s2, s3,...`.

```
from itertools import *

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

a = [1,2,3,4]

for item in unpair(pairwise(a)):
   print item # should print 1,2,3,4
```

How to write `unpair` as a generator, without resorting to lists?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you give more context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe:

```
def unpair(iterable):
    p = iter(iterable)
    return chain(next(p, []), (x[1] for x in p))
```

Comment: Nice, but how about an edge case (empty iterable)?

Comment: it returns an exception - StopIteration - which is exactly what it should return, isn't it?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman The problem is that it raises StopIteration already when called, when the iteration has not yet begun. For example, `list(unpair([]))` raises the exception instead of returning an empty list.

Comment: that looks like it makes it work. and with the fix, it's also faster than my solution (for the small list shown, this one is 2.67 uS vs. 4.04 uS for mine)

Comment: With Jon's edit this seems to work fine. Also, `from_iterable` appears superfluous - we only have two arguments.

Comment: Thanks to everyone this is so much better than it was that I've made it community wiki!  Thanks esp. @JonClements, thg435.

Answer (score 4):

This should be it:

```py
def unpairwise(iterable):
    for i, (fst, snd) in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == 0:
            yield fst
        yield snd
```

If you are concerned by the `if` being evaluated at each loop, you could of course do:

```
def unpairwise(iterable):
    fst, snd = iterable.next()
    yield fst
    yield snd
    for fst, snd in iterable:
        yield snd
```

Comment: Good one, but I'm not happy with the `if` statement being executed on each iteration while in fact it's only needed once.

Comment: @thg435 yeah, to be honest, I had some concerns too... I included the version without the condition. It's less elegant for the eyes although.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def unpair(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    head = next(it)
    yield head[0]
    yield head[1]
    for fst, snd in it:
        yield snd
```

Comment: Actually, it turned out that your code works just fine with an empty generator (since, unlike DSM's it's a generator itself).

Answer (score 2):

a version of DSM's that is concise, but works for an empty list:

```
from itertools import islice, chain
def unpair(iterable):
    p = iter(iterable)
    return chain(chain(*islice(p,1)),(x[1] for x in p))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def unpair(iterable):
...     x, y = zip(*iterable)
...     return chain([x[0]], y)
```